# Ionic sqlite error on select request, returns null

Tags: angularjs, cordova, sqlite, ionic-framework

i have an issue when i try to get a row from my Database, i'm saving a profile data in a table called "Learners" when i save it, i don't get any problem, but if i call a Select request it returns me a NULL object, so i don't know where is the error, this is my code fragment:

Controller.js

```js
$scope.getProfileWord2 = function(){
            return Words.getProfileWord().then(function(detalle){
              if (!detalle) {
                $scope.profileWord = {
                  Id_words: null
                };  
              }else{
                $scope.profileWord = detalle;
              }
              return detalle;
            });    

        };
```

```js
$scope.getProfileWord2().then(function(detalle) {
                                                    if (detalle===null || detalle===undefined) {
                                                    $scope.profileWord = {
                                                      title: null,
                                                      Id_words: null
                                                     };  
                                                    console.log("El Id Word es : " + $scope.profileWord.Id_words);
                                                    //return "/app/inicio";
                                                  }else{
                                                      console.log("El Id Word es : " + $scope.profileWord.Id_words);
                                                      $scope.profileWord = detalle;
                                                      $scope.profile={
                                                        name_sound_path: src,
                                                        word_id: $scope.profileWord.Id_words,
                                                        profile_image_path: $scope.imgURI,
                                                        congrats_path: src2,
                                                        title: content,
                                                        content: content,
                                                        letter_id: $scope.profileLetter.Id,
                                                        selected: 1

                                                      };
                                                      Words.addProfile($scope.profile);
                                                            
                                                  }
                                                  });
```

Notice in this line `Words.addProfile($scope.profile);` i use the service.js to add a row to the DB

Service.js

```js
 self.addProfile = function(word) {
    var parameters = [word.name_sound_path,word.word_id,word.profile_image_path,word.congrats_path,word.title,word.content,word.letter_id,word.selected];
    return DBA.query("INSERT INTO learners (name_sound_path, word_id, profile_image_path, congrats_path, title, content, letter_id, selected) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?.?,?,?)", parameters);
  };
```

Then when i call my controller i call this fucntion, which is called at begin:

```js
$scope.getProfileRow = function() {
    Words.getProfileSimple().then(function(single){
      if (single === null || single === undefined) {
      $scope.editWordRow = {
          title: null,
          congrats_path: null,
          name_sound_path: null,
          profile_image_path: null
      };  
      
      }
      else 
      {
      $scope.editWordRow = single;
     
      }
  
          
    });
      
  };
  $scope.getProfileRow();
```

that function execute a Select from Database using this service function:

```js
self.getProfileSimple = function() {
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM learners WHERE selected = 1")
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
      });
  };
```

When i save a profile data, i set "selected" value to 1, so if i saved the profile data, why the select request is returning NULL, i will appreciate any help, regards...

Comment: Are you sure the selected value is 1? Have you tried using `.catch` after the query to see if there are any errors for either the insert or select?

Comment: im not sure, how can i use the catch?, where?

Comment: i'm using this function  `self.query = function (query, parameters) {
    parameters = parameters || [];
    var q = $q.defer();

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
        .then(function (result) {
          q.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
          console.warn('I found an error');
          console.warn(error);
          console.log(error.code + ' / ' + error.message);
          q.reject(error);
        });
    });
    return q.promise;
  };`

Comment: then for example i call it here:  `self.getProfileSimple = function() {
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM learners WHERE selected = 1")
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
      });
  };`  wherw DBA is a factory that i call in another factories

Comment: when i try to insert a row, the console launch this error:` I found an error services.js:17
Object {message: "prepare statement failed with error: 1", code: 0} services.js:18
0 / prepare statement failed with error: 1 `

Comment: i solved it, my bad on this line `("INSERT INTO learners (name_sound_path, word_id, profile_image_path, congrats_path, title, content, letter_id, selected) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?.?,?,?)", parameters);` on addProfile function, thanks!! note the dot instead comma